# bash: how to print an integer in hex to a specific length

Tags: bash, hex, printf

I am trying to dump the decimal integer values from one file in a hex format.
I do have a file with integer values in decimal.

```
$ more test.dat_trim
2 9
0 -11
7 -17
14 -1
```

I am trying to print this integer in hex. I know also that the integer values are small enough to fit on 2 bytes. I want the output to be on 2 bytes. But then when i am trying:

```
declare -i i;for i in $(<test.dat_trim);do printf "%.2x\n" $i; done;
02
09
00
fffffffffffffff5
07
ffffffffffffffef
0e
ffffffffffffffff
```

Basically `printf "%.2x\n"` it is only working for positive number. How can i make it work for negative also?
Just to clarify what i am expecting: The result should be like this:

```
02
09
00
f5
07
ef
0e
ff
```

meaning that i want for the negative values to be sign extended only on 1 byte.

Comment: You should make it clearer exactly what output you expect, by providing the ideal output for your sample input.

Comment: Referring the update: Why do you want this, as it would give you `0` for `-256` as well as for `0`. And `1` for -255 as well as for `1` and so on ...

Comment: this is part of a subroutine that verifies packing of data. basically unpacks binary files and verifies them with original unpacked version.there is another subroutine which check the magnitude of data and if we had for instance 256 i would dump on 2 bytes instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Printing signed hex values is uncommon, so there is no conversion specifier providing this.

You could use the following work around:

```
for i in $(<test.dat_trim); do
  if [ $i -ge 0 ]; then
    printf " 0x%02x\n" $i; 
  else
    printf "%c0x%02x\n" '-' $[$i * -1]; 
  fi
done;
```

---

Referrig the update to the question:

Just replace this line

```
printf "%c0x%02x\n" '-' $[$i * -1];
```

with this

```
printf " 0x%02x\n" $[256 + $i];
```

This however, only works for the numbers >= -256.

Comment: 0x02
 0x09
 0x00
-0x0b
 0x07
-0x11
 0x0e
-0x01
Almoust there. But it is printing the sign and not sign extending the negative value. The sign should be encoded into the the sign extension.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in awk, that handles negative numbers also:

```
awk '{printf "0x%x%s0x%x\n", $1, OFS, $2}' OFS='\t' file
0x2     0x9
0x0     0xfffffff5
0x7     0xffffffef
0xe     0xffffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda silly but what the heck:

```
xargs -a test.dat_trim bash -c 'printf %.2s\\n $(printf %02x\\n $* | rev) | rev' _
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried printf("%04x\n",i)?

Comment: Did you try? This would still print the complement for the negative values.

Comment: Kindly explain what is your intended output for -1 example?

Comment: Mine? The OP is looking for something like `-0x01` I suspect.

Comment: I thought he wanted it to be on 2 bytes which is 4 characters hex value.

Comment: Ahyes, I also wondered about *output to be on 2 bytes*" but concluded from the OPs example "*2 nibbles*" were meant.